# writing a python basic python program

Tags: python

For homework I am writing a program that:

- Reads in a series of positive integers
- Writes out the product of all the integers less than 25
- Writes out the sum of all the integers greater than or equal to 25

Code:

```
n1 = [5,10,15,25,30,35]
tp = 1 #totalproduct
ts = 0 #totalsum
for x in n1:
    if x < 25:
    tp= (tp*x)
    print(tp)
for x in n1:
    if x >= 25:
    ts = (ts+x)
    print(ts)
```

It does what I want it to but it prints out:

```
5
50
750 #this is the total product
25
55
90#this is the total sum
```

How do I make it so that it only prints out final loop which are the totals and not print out the other numbers?

Comment: There are resources available for learning python over here. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

Comment: yup, try first and if you really got stuck, post again with your code and error messages. You will learn better that way.

Comment: You should start the same way you would do with c++ or any language. Divide your problem in simpler subproblems. Solve each subproblem separately. Put it all together. Do you know how to read a positive integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the writing of the sums and products out of the loops:

```
n1 = [5,10,15,25,30,35]
tp = 1 #totalproduct
ts = 0 #totalsum
for x in n1:
    if x < 25:
    tp= (tp*x)
print(tp)
for x in n1:
    if x >= 25:
    ts = (ts+x)
print(ts)
```

does the job.